# Not the correct rights to delete a file running a Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, delete-file

I have a problem on a server where running a Laravel application, it does not have the rights to delete a file. But running a single php file deleting the file with `unlink($file);` does work.

File:

`-rw-r--r--  1 user1 user1 27979 Dec 18  2021 myfile.pdf`

Folder (/storage/customfolder/):

`drwxrwxr-x  2 user1 user1 4096 Sep 26 12:32 customFolder`

try to delete a file:

```
if (File::exists($path)) {
   if(File::delete($path)) {
     /// file is deleted, throw a party
   }
}
```

So i checked the file/folder permission and the current user:

```
// check the user 
get_current_user();
=> "user1"

// check if file exists
file_exists('/******/shared/storage/customfolder/myfile.pdf')
=> true

// check if is writable 
 is_writable('/******/shared/storage/customfolder/myfile.pdf')
=> false

// check the file permissions
substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('/******/shared/storage/customfolder/myfile.pdf')), -4);
=> 0644 
 
// check the file owner 
posix_getpwuid(fileowner('/******/shared/storage/customfolder/myfile.pdf')) 
=>  [
        "name" => "user1",
        ....
    ]

// check the folder permissions: 
substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('/******/shared/storage/customfolder/')), -4);
0775

// check the folder owner
posix_getpwuid(fileowner('/******/shared/storage/customfolder/'))
=>  [
        "name" => "user1",
        ....
    ]
```

check if unlink would work.. (getting frustrated now)

```
unlink('/******/shared/storage/customfolder/myfile.pdf')
=> false
```

Now the thing is, deleting the file in a single php file does work

```
<?php
$file = "/******/shared/storage/customfolder/myfile.pdf";

echo file_exists($file);

if (file_exists($file)) {
 echo unlink($file);
}
```

Anybody an idea on what could be going on?
Thank you so much!

cheers,
Pim

Comment: If you have two PHP scripts doing an "unlink" and these two scripts are launched in the same way and with the same rights. So there's a problem with one of the scripts, isn't it...? In your example ````unlink(/******/shared/storage/customfolder/myfile.pdf')```` an opening apostrophe is missing

Comment: Could it be that at some point before you try to delete the file it might have been opened for reading and therefore is blocked from being deleted?